# In Antares Dawn, who is Cynthia?

Tags: antares-dawn

In the first chapter of Michael McCollum's classic Sci-fi novel, [Antares Dawn](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1929381069), Drake and Wilson have [the following conversation](http://www.smashwords.com/extreader/read/12503/6/antares-dawn) on the way to the Admiralty building:

> "How is that young lady of yours?" Wilson asked as the driver maneuvered the car into the heavy traffic headed for Homeport.
>
> "Cynthia? She's fine, sir." Drake gestured at the overnight bag. "I was hoping for a chance to see her this trip."
>
> Some unidentifiable emotion flashed across Wilson's features. "Sorry, Captain, but you won't be on the ground that long."

I assumed Cynthia was Drake's wife, but I am now halfway through the book, and he seems to be developing a love-interest in another woman.  I did a text search of the book and [its](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1929381093) [sequels](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1929381085), but Cynthia is never mentioned again.  Also, there seems to be no mention of this problem on the Internet.

So, **who is Cynthia?**  Do we find out later in the book (perhaps by a different name?)  Or was that passage just a huge glaring oversight by the author that somehow no one has ever noticed before?

Comment: I felt that my answer was pretty comprehensive. Is there anything else you'd like to see addressed before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 3):

I can confirm that Cynthia is never mentioned again, nor does her existence seem to bother Mr Drake in his ambitions to do [the zero-g jiggy-jiggy](https://youtu.be/YAjR4SniykY?t=7s) with the "*highly desirable*" and "*lithe-bodied*" Miss Bethany Lindquist a few pages later.

The fact that Cynthia is referred to as his "young lady", the fact that she barely merits a sentence, the fact that Drake accepts an offworld posting without even the need for a conversation with her, straight after having not seen her for nearly a year would all strongly suggest that she's his occasional girlfriend and nothing more.

---

Out-of-universe, Michael McCollum's mother was called [Cynthia](http://www.winonadailynews.com/lifestyles/announcements/obituaries/cynthia-diane-quall-mccollum/article_599f11bc-5f9a-11e3-b48c-001a4bcf887a.html). The character was almost certainly intended in order to name-check her, in much the same way as several of the ships + characters mentioned elsewhere in the novel (the Starship **Catherine**, **Elizabeth** Esperanza,  **Robert** H. Goddard and Bethany **Patricia** Lindquist) are all named after members of the author's family including his wife, children and grandmother.

As to the reason why he decided to make his mother into a portside floozy, you'd have to ask Dr Freud.

Comment: His wife was named Robert?

Comment: @Xantec - I'll admit that it's a bit of an unusual name for a girl; http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BLTR8qYWJbQ